# Is a 64 bit random ID good enough for about 10 million entries?

Tags: random, uniqueidentifier, unique-key

I was inspired by this [unique id code](https://github.com/WardCunningham/Smallest-Federated-Wiki/blob/master/server/sinatra/random_id.rb) to generate a random 64 bit identifier.

My question: will this be good enough for about 10 million entries?

```
def self.generateId
  (0..15).collect{(rand*16).to_i.to_s(16)}.join
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is classic birthday problem.

With `m=10^7` and `n=10^20` (Since `2^64` ~ `10^20`), and the collision probability is given by:

`p = 1 - exp(-m^2/(2*n))`

Gives a collision probability of `5e-07`

I would say sampling without replacement is your best option.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "sampling without replacement"?

Comment: imagine a set of numbered items in a bag & draw one at random. Since the item is drawn and not replaced, it will never repeat. Most `math` libraries have support for sampling without replacement.

Comment: I see. In my case that won't be an option, because ids are generated by many different clients that are not aware of each other.

Comment: @Mark how do you plan to seed your RNG on different clients?

Comment: @e4e5f5 No, I actually use `arc4random()`

Answer (score 0):

I would make it 128 bit long, that way you don't have to worry for sure about 10M records

Answer (score 0):

2^64 is about EDIT: <strike>10^31</strike> 10^21, which is larger than 10^7 (10 million) by a factor of 10^14. So it is nearly completely safe to use only 64 bits.

Comment: That's not right, sorry.  `2^64 = (2^10)^6 * 2^4 = 1024^6 * 2^4 ~ 10^18 * 10 ~ 10^19`

Comment: You are right, my fault. What I wanted to say is: 2^10 is about 10^3, so 2^64 is about 10^21, so 10^31 was a typo, it should have read 10^21. Anyway, 10^21 is larger than 10^7 by a factor of 10^14, any my argument is still valid. I have edited my answer accordingly.